# I am having trouble with prisma studio. Prisma studio is not working correctly

Tags: node.js, linux, express, prisma

Every time I run npx prisma studio it returns with the following error. If I update or install prisma then it run correctly. And if I close my project and try to run npx prisma studio it gives error again.

```
❯ npx prisma studio
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Prisma Studio is up on http://localhost:5555
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

```
❯ npx prisma version
Environment variables loaded from .env
prisma                  : 5.3.0
@prisma/client          : 5.3.0
Current platform        : debian-openssl-1.1.x
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine e90b936d84779543cbe0e494bc8b9d7337fad8e4 (at node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+engines@5.3.0/node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node)
Schema Engine           : schema-engine-cli e90b936d84779543cbe0e494bc8b9d7337fad8e4 (at node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+engines@5.3.0/node_modules/@prisma/engines/schema-engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x)
Schema Wasm             : @prisma/prisma-schema-wasm 5.3.0-36.e90b936d84779543cbe0e494bc8b9d7337fad8e4
Default Engines Hash    : e90b936d84779543cbe0e494bc8b9d7337fad8e4
Studio                  : 0.494.0
```

My Os Config :
Os: Zorin os core 16.3
Ram: 8gb DDR3